# Batch script to generate a random date to be integrated into a command that applies to a batch of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If anyone can help me, I'm having a hard time

I am using `timestomper` to change the date of my files, I would like to randomize the date for each file to get random sorting.

This is what I've done so far, the script is definitely very bad, but I've tried...

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set /a _day=(!RANDOM!*25/32768)+1
    Set /a _month=(!RANDOM!*12/32768)+1
    Set /a _hours=(!RANDOM!*22/32768)+1
    Set /a _minutes=(!RANDOM!*60/32768)+1
for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (
    timestomper -z %_month%-%_day%-2022 %_hours%:%_minutes%:01 -p "%%v"
    
)
```

the output of my script:

```
a.jpg 04/12/2010 10:20
b.jpg 04/12/2010 10:20
c.jpg 04/12/2010 10:20
d.jpg 04/12/2010 10:20
```

What I want is a randomly generated date for each file:

```
a.jpg 04/12/2010 10:20
b.jpg 10/02/2001 22:02
c.jpg 01/02/2004 15:27
d.jpg 12/20/2008 08:13
```

What timstomper needs is a date and a path to the file:

```
timestomper -z 10-20-1994 14:2:01 -p C:\full\path
```

I hope to be clear in my request

Comment: The problem is that you _first_ generate a random timestamp and then use _the same timestamp_ for all the files! You must move the `for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (` command before the first `Set /a _day=` command and change the percents in `timestomper` invocation by exclamation marks, excepting in the `"%%v"` part, of course!  PS - I suggest you to use shorter and concise question titles, like "Problem generating random numbers"

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I tried what you advised, I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, but it doesn't work.
I placed `for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do timestomper -z !_month!-!_day!-2022 !_hours!:!_minutes!:01 -p "%%v"` before the variables and changed my % to !, but nothing happened. 
The script literally executes this: `timestomper -z !_month!-!_day!-2022 !_hours!:!_minutes!:01 -p "a.jpg"` without applying random numbers.

Ok I will apply your advice for the other questions

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is your original code:

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set /a _day=(!RANDOM!*25/32768)+1
    Set /a _month=(!RANDOM!*12/32768)+1
    Set /a _hours=(!RANDOM!*22/32768)+1
    Set /a _minutes=(!RANDOM!*60/32768)+1
for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (
    timestomper -z %_month%-%_day%-2022 %_hours%:%_minutes%:01 -p "%%v"

)
```

In my advice I said: *"You must move the `for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (` command before the first `Set /a _day=` command and change the percents in `timestomper` invocation by exclamation marks, excepting in the "%%v" part, of course!"*

Let's follow these instructions step by step:

*"You must move the `for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (` command before the first `Set /a _day=` command"*

That is:

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                                              to here <----+
    Set /a _day=(!RANDOM!*25/32768)+1                      |
    Set /a _month=(!RANDOM!*12/32768)+1                    |
    Set /a _hours=(!RANDOM!*22/32768)+1                    |
    Set /a _minutes=(!RANDOM!*60/32768)+1                  |
for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (                    from here >--+
    timestomper -z %_month%-%_day%-2022 %_hours%:%_minutes%:01 -p "%%v"

)
```

... giving:

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (
    Set /a _day=(!RANDOM!*25/32768)+1
    Set /a _month=(!RANDOM!*12/32768)+1
    Set /a _hours=(!RANDOM!*22/32768)+1
    Set /a _minutes=(!RANDOM!*60/32768)+1
    timestomper -z %_month%-%_day%-2022 %_hours%:%_minutes%:01 -p "%%v"

)
```

Then *"change the percents in `timestomper` invocation by exclamation marks, excepting in the "%%v" part"*

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%v in (*.jpg) do (
    Set /a _day=(!RANDOM!*25/32768)+1
    Set /a _month=(!RANDOM!*12/32768)+1
    Set /a _hours=(!RANDOM!*22/32768)+1
    Set /a _minutes=(!RANDOM!*60/32768)+1
    timestomper -z !_month!-!_day!-2022 !_hours!:!_minutes!:01 -p "%%v"

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your more detailed explanation.
I finally made it!
I did exactly what you told me to do, but it didn't work. The error came from elsewhere, I understood that the random number generated did not run well.
But now I have precisely what I want, a random sort in explorer without changing the filename.